# Uber ERROR Invalid scope requested

Tags: uber-api

Here is my auth url

https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id={{client id}}&response_type=code&scope=profile request

Is theire any issue in above url.

Comment: If you open the above URL in a browser with the {{client id}} replaced by the actual value and then you login are you redirected to the default redirect URI ? Do you see any error in the URL parameters? Did you set a redirect URI set in the Uber Developers Dashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the `request` scope configured in your app? The list of scopes in the `scope` parameter has to be a subset of the scopes you configured.

You could try the same request without the `scope` parameter. That'll default to whatever scopes you configured (you'll need at least one for your authorization to go through).

Comment: Without scope parameter, it works but user could not get request scope. For that this parameter we must set but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

They forgot an 's' in the documentation file.

Try `scopes=...` instead of `scope=...`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try replacing the spaces with `%20`, like so?

`https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id={{client id}}&response_type=code&scope=profile%20request`